# Display uploaded files In Angular 14 and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I tried to display the list of files loaded in a specific folder and displayed in my angular page. Someone can help me with this code

ASP.NET Core code:

```cs
[HttpGet, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[Route("Files")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Display()
{
    string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "RH/"));
    List<FileViewModel> lstFile = new List<FileViewModel>();

    foreach(var file in filepaths)
    {
        lstFile.Add(new FileViewModel { FileName = Path.GetFileName(file), FilePath = Path.GetFullPath(file) });
    }

    return Ok(new { lstFile });
}
```

Angular `service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileUploadService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:7125/api/Employe';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.baseUrl}/upload`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
  getFiles(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/Files`);
  }
}
```

Angular `Component.ts`:

```
selectedFiles?: FileList;
  progressInfos: any[] = [];
  message: string[] = [];
  fileInfos?: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private formBuilder : UntypedFormBuilder,private employeeService: EmployeeService,
  private router:Router,private uploadService: FileUploadService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileInfos = this.uploadService.getFiles();
}

//upload Files
selectFiles(event:any): void {
        this.message = [];
        this.progressInfos = [];
        this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
      }
      uploadFiles(): void {
        this.message = [];

        if (this.selectedFiles) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
            this.upload(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
          }
        }

      }
      upload(idx: number, file: File): void {
        this.progressInfos[idx] = { value: 0, fileName: file.name };

        if (file) {
          this.uploadService.upload(file).subscribe({
            next: (event: any) => {
              if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                this.progressInfos[idx].value = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
              } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const msg = 'Uploaded the file successfully: ' + file.name;
                this.message.push(msg);
                this.fileInfos = this.uploadService.getFiles();
              }
            },
            error: (err: any) => {
              this.progressInfos[idx].value = 0;
              const msg = 'Could not upload the file: ' + file.name;
              this.message.push(msg);
              this.fileInfos = this.uploadService.getFiles();
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

Angular `component.html`:

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="inputNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <label class="btn btn-default p-0">
            <input type="file" multiple (change)="selectFiles($event)" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                [disabled]="!selectedFiles"
                (click)="uploadFiles()">
            Upload
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let progressInfo of progressInfos" class="mb-2">
    <span>{{ progressInfo.fileName }}</span>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info"
             role="progressbar"
             attr.aria-valuenow="{{ progressInfo.value }}"
             aria-valuemin="0"
             aria-valuemax="100"
             [ngStyle]="{ width: progressInfo.value + '%' }">
             {{ progressInfo.value }}%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="message.length" class="alert alert-secondary my-3" role="alert">
    <ul *ngFor="let msg of message; let i = index">
        <li>{{ msg }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">List of Files</div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"
        *ngFor="let file of fileInfos | async">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{{ file.url }}">{{ file.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to display files uploaded from the server backend in Angular component and download it

Comment: Could you explain what is not happening that you expect to happen? Alternatively, could you explain what is happening that you do not want to happen?

Comment: i add button for uplaod files i want when i upload it i will dispaly it in the table

Comment: Those are your requirements. You need to explain what is not working. It is not clear from your post what is not working.

Comment: for uploaded file it ok but i can't dispaly files liste  with URL in component.html